# Saving values from datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I am new to c#. I have been trying to add values from my datagrid to mysql but in vain and i really need your help. The values are automatically generated after a time interval of 1 sec and i need to insert them to the mysql in the same time interval. Here are the codes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace BLIND_SHOPPING_SYSTEM
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private DataTable m_TagDataTable = new DataTable("Tag List");

        long passiveID = 0;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.m_TagDataTable.Columns.Add("TagID");
        }

        private void btn_GenerateID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (passiveID < 10)
            {
                passiveID = passiveID + 1;
                //listBox1.Items.Add(passiveID);
                //this.m_TagDataTable.Columns.Add("TagID");
                this.dataGridView1.DataSource = m_TagDataTable;
                DataRow dr = m_TagDataTable.NewRow();
                dr["TagID"] = passiveID;
                m_TagDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);

            }
            else
                // Application.Exit();
                Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private void btn_Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Please kindly help me.

Comment: Shouldn't you only bind the table to the datagridview once? It seems wrong to have it in the timer tick event handler

Comment: Yes..I have changed it..thank you..but i'm still stuck with the insertion into mysql problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a DataTableAdapter and specify the Update command, see here for some examples ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233819(v=vs.80).aspx